# На полях форума?

Tags: значение-слов

Словари утверждают, что, к примеру, и у исландцев, и у русских, и у шведов полем издавна называли место боя. Утверждение подкрепляется старыми пословицами (Коли у поля стал, так бей наповал) и названиями (ц. Троица у старых поль).

Как же относиться к терминологии в разных сообщениях, типа такого: *«На полях Петербургского международного экономического форума компания подписала ряд соглашений о сотрудничестве, в частности с зарубежными концернами»*?

И такого: *«Ещё лет пять назад было невозможно себе представить, что в прайм-тайм американского ТВ на полном серьёзе будет обсуждаться необходимость срочного импичмента действующего президента из-за того, что он может попросить Путина "нагнуть избирательное поле" в свою пользу»*.

Comment: > и у исландцев, и у русских, и у шведов полем издавна называли место боя Ну, допустим, что издавна называли. Какое это имеет отношение к нынешним временам? Сейчас-то не называют.

Comment: Футбольное поле — поле для обнимашек?

Comment: В отличие от нашего строгого г-на behemothus ничего плохого в таких выражениях не вижу. На полях так на полях.

Comment: @shampar обнимашки тут дело десятое. Футбольное поле - протяженный пространственный объект, ровный, подвергшийся воздействию человека...  Ну то есть масса критериев за этот вариант. Да еще и калька с английского. Но вы сделали чудо. Nimand научился писать "г-н behemothus" без идиотской в таком контексте собаки.

Comment: И зачем так нервничать, г-н @behemothus? Но вы все равно не правы: у слова "поле" масса значений, а не только "протяженный пространственный объект". Так что зря вы ругаетесь.

Comment: Зря я вас похвалил.

Comment: Лучше бы они "площадки" приплетали, а так - даже плохим переводом не объяснить. Обычное чиновничье (если не журналистское) косноязычие с его вездесущими "полями" и "высоко поднятыми планками", которые "в том числе".

Comment: @Alex_ander А почему плохим переводом не объяснить? Я-то как раз плохой калькой с английского и объясняю. "On the fiield of" - означает примерно в поле ("влияния", "воздействие"), в русском есть аналог - в физике, математике (потециальное поле, например), но оно почти совершенно неупотребимо во множественном числе, особенно если речь идет об одном влияющем обїекте.

Comment: Потому что этот конкретный текст - русского происхождения. Сейчас вижу у Sharon прямую попытку найти истоки в другом языке - похоже, что виноват-таки  какой-то старый перевод (см. коммент к её ответу).

Comment: @Alex_ander вы так быстро ответили, что я не успел мысль изложить)). Посмотрите еще раз, если не трудно.

Comment: Я думаю, что исходным словом было не field (см. ссылку у Sharon, по которой рассматривают французское marge) - сочетание field + forum выводит поиском на сельское хозяйство.

Answer (score 3):

***На полях*** Петербургского международного экономического форума компания подписала ряд соглашений о сотрудничестве, в частности с зарубежными концернами».

1) Как оказывается, выражение это отнюдь не новое. Вот, к примеру, запись 2014 года (там "на полях" дается в кавычках): *Путин **"на полях"** форума АТЭС встретится с лидерами нескольких стран.*

2) Выражение можно считать журналистским **сленгом** с примерно таким значением: **на мероприятиях и встречах различного формата, проводимых в рамках форума.**

3) **Смысл не очень ясный.**

Поле может иметь значение **общего интеллектуального пространства** ("поле деятельности", обозначенное в словаре). Иными словами, ***на полях*** – это ***на просторах*** чего-либо, как на просторах Интертнета.

Но оно же может обозначать и нечто **выходящее за рамки основных мероприятий** (сравнить: на полях книги, то есть где-то в стороне).

4) Со словом мучаются переводчики, например:

"Что-то подобное возникло у меня при попытке понять смысл **модного сейчас у журналистов выражения**: "на полях" какого-то политического события. Например, "на полях ГА ООН", "на полях саммита нормандской четверки", "на полях саммита СНГ". 
Попытки осмыслить это понятие через французский язык дали три варианта..."  http://www.trworkshop.net/forum/viewtopic.php?f=23&t=61205

5) Слово пытаются осмыслить и обычные пользователи русского языка: **Что означает выражение "встреча на полях саммита"? О чьих встречах речь?** И вот забавный ответ: "Только **несовременный чел** не знает что это такое. Люди, но не простые, а главы государств, встречаются "тет а тет"..."

http://www.bolshoyvopros.ru/questions/2994730-chto-oznachaet-vyrazhenie-vstrecha-na-poljah-sammita-o-chih-vstrechah-rech.html

6) **Вывод.**   В приведенной фразе речь, вероятно,  всё-таки идет о мероприятиях вне основной программы, **когда встречаются руководители компаний и подписывают двусторонние соглашения.**

Comment: В свете значения французского marge и английского margin (отступ, _поля_ страницы), речь идёт о _кулуарах_, слове, не найденном ранее каким-нибудь самодеятельным переводчиком отдельных слов, из числа журналистов, и в результате получившем хождение в журналистской среде.

Comment: @Alex_ander не-не. Не о кулуарах, вернее сказать - не только о них.

Comment: @Alex_ander А как Вы думаете, каким синонимом можно заменить "на полях"? Синоним должен быть по возможности кратким, а также должен точно передавать смысл сказанного. Как отредактировать фразу?

Comment: Если речь о раздельной работе частей форума, то "площадки", "секции", а если о частных договорённостях вне общей повески дня, не вижу ничего плохого в "кулуарах".

Comment: Мне интересно, как исправить именно это предложение. ""В кулуарах" здесь вроде бы не подходит, там только решение о подписании соглашения можно принять при неофициальном общении.

Comment: Можно даже "в рамках" (временных, территориальных, организационных), ведь регламент таких форумов предусматривает возможность заключения двустронних договоров.

Comment: Спасибо. Действительно, "в рамках" - это обычный термин, правда,  он отвечает  на вопрос "как", а  в том предложении скорее указано место (где). Вот и получается, что слово-то  "косноязычное", а точный синоним для него трудно подобрать.

Comment: «На полях книги, то есть где-то в стороне...» ==== Скорее (не в стороне), а вне блока текста, в котором содержание утверждено как стратегия, на свободных участках листа, как выглядят заметки или правка по факту.

Comment: Ну да, я именно это имела в ввиду.  Но если отвлечься от реальных заметок на полях страниц, то это выражение приобретает значение "в стороне".

Answer (score 2):

> Как же относиться к терминологии в разных сообщениях, типа такого: «На
>   полях Петербургского международного экономического

Плохо относиться.
Это неприятный, стилистически ничем не оправданный, речевой штамп, однако к событиям давно минувших дней отношения не имеет.

У саммита нет и не может быть полей ни в каком значении. 
Еще "на лугах" саммита можно - для полного впечатления. Или "на равнинах".

Возможно,  кто-то видит в таком использовании намек на "поле" как на место, где что-то выращивается, возделывается... Тогда такое использование было бы оправдано, но ведь это совсем не обязательное требованию к полю. Иного объяснения у меня нет, склоняюсь к мысли считать ***обычным косноязычием***.

Answer (score 1):

***На полях*** Петербургского международного экономического форума компания подписала ряд соглашений о сотрудничестве, в частности с зарубежными концернами».

**На полях форума...** Я пытаюсь вслушаться в это выражение, и вот в значении некого пространства, пусть даже виртуального (в переносном смысле), оно мне кажется **совершенно неподходящим.** Сразу же возникают ассоциации с полями сражений, а также колхозными и футбольными полями.

Но вот когда мы говорим о заметках **на полях рукописи**, мы же не думаем о неком протяженном пространстве поля, и такое выражение **не кажется нам странным.**

Кстати, эти заметки не обязательно карандашом записаны, о них можно сказать так: **замечу на полях, тут впору сделать заметку на полях.** Так в виде вводных сочетаний и предложений обозначаются авторские отступления от основной темы.

Вот и у журналистов ***поля форума*** – это, вероятно,  общение вне основной программы, поэтому надо **сделать над собой усилие и настроить слух именно на это значение слова**. Когда мы перестаем "видеть" **привычные для нашего воображения поля**, то слово не кажется таким уж нелепым и косноязычным.

Возможно, журналисты свой слух уже "настроили".